# tensorflow affine transform fill value

Tags: image, opencv, tensorflow, affinetransform

But I'm trying to replicate:

```
img_tr = cv2.warpAffine(img, m, (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE), borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,
                        borderValue=(FILL_VALUE,FILL_VALUE,FILL_VALUE),
                        flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

I'm using

```
    img_tr = tf.contrib.image.transform(img,
                                        affine_transform,
                                        interpolation='BILINEAR',
                                        output_shape=[IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE],
                                        name='affine_warp')
```

> Transformed coordinates outside of the input image will be filled with
>   zeros.

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/image/transform

Is there a way to set fill value?

Answer (score 0):

When we trace the source, we can find the low level implementation is in the file [image_ops.h](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.15/tensorflow/contrib/image/kernels/image_ops.h). The fill_vaule is set to zero in (line 65, 74, 86), so the only way to change it is to edit and rebuild the source.